# Xamarin.forms - checkbox trigger another checkbox's CheckedChanged event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin.forms app, I have a listview with checkboxes for the selection of the individual cell. What I am trying to do is multi select the checkboxes inside the listview by providing a "select all" checkbox outside the listview.The Multiselection works fine. For the "select all" checkbox click and individual checkbox click, I am performing some actions like an API Call. The Problem I am facing is Whenever I Click on the "select all" checkbox, the checkbox changed event of individual checkbox gets triggered.I know its natural But is there any way to prevent it like subscribe or unsubscribe the changed event of individual checkbox or something?

[image: Screenshot]

**Xaml**

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinitions Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinitions Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>                          
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Text="Select All" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="LawnGreen" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" >                                         
        </Label>
        <CheckBox x:Name="MultiselectCheckbox" ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8" CheckedChanged="MultiSelectCheckBox_CheckedChanged"  IsChecked="False" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Color="LawnGreen"></CheckBox>
        </StackLayout>          
        <ListView 
         x:Name="Listview"          
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                  
         ItemTapped="DistrictList_ItemTapped"
         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                                        <DataTemplate >
                                            <ViewCell >
                                                <ViewCell.View>
                                                    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">                                                      
                                                        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Snow" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                                            </Label>
                                                            <CheckBox CheckedChanged="Single_CheckedChanged" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Color="LightBlue" HorizontalOptions="End" >
                                                            </CheckBox>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                    </Frame>
                                                </ViewCell.View>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>                                                                                                 
      </Grid>
```

**Multiselect Checkbox checked event**

```
    private  void MultiSelectCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {

     if (!e.Value)
        {
         foreach (MyData TS in MyObject)
                    {
                        TS.Selected = false;
                    }
        }

     else{
        foreach (MyData TS in MyObject)
                    {
                        TS.Selected = true;
                    }

                    PerformSomeAction();
         }  
    }
```

**Single selection Checkbox changed event**

```
     private void Single_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
                {

                 if (!e.Value)
                    {
                    }   
                 else{                              
                                PerformSomeAction();
                     }



}
```

**Data Model**

```
 public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public string name { get; set; }
            private bool selected;
            public bool Selected
            {

                get
                {
                    return selected;
                }

                set
                {
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        selected = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you use a boolean flag (like `fromMultiSelect`) to restrict the single checkbox event?? Will it be enough for your purpose?

Comment: @Nikhileshwar The problem is user have enough freedom to multiselect or single select as they like. So I think keeping a boolean value is not sufficient

Comment: From what I understand what you are doing is making an API call based on selections? So if I select options A, B and C so only that data comes and if that is the case you are doing this wrong what you should be doing is always get all the data and then you rule out whatever is not relevant, Feel free to ask questions if you have any!

Comment: @FreakyAli Thanks for the reply. The Data will receive according to the checkbox item. So I cant fetch the whole data initially.When ever we  click select all, there is an Id corresponds to each item and will pass as list and get the data. If we click any single checkbox again API call with corresponding id will pass and obatin the result

Comment: I can manage these single and multi selection seperatly. Bu if we use these features together then the mentioned issue will happens

Comment: What I am saying is you always have the list of possible options then why are you not getting the whole data that is how you should be handling this in the first place! AFAIK that is the best solution!

Comment: @FreakyAli  I wish.But the API is not under my control. So is there any other workarounds to solve this issue?

Comment: @FreakyAli when user click on select all option, I just dont want the individual checkbox trigger.

Comment: AFAIK there is no direct way to do this you will have to add a boolean and handle this yourself!

Comment: As you are checking the individual CheckBox in the `MultiSelectCheckBox_CheckedChanged ` method why not set a boolean to true there. And check that boolean in the `Single_CheckedChanged ` before `PerformSomeAction ` and set the boolean back to false after the for loop in `MultiSelectCheckBox_CheckedChanged`. I don't think this might cause an issue. Will it??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree with @ Nikhileshwar , you could define some properties to get the different condition .And since you had used MVVM, you would better put all logic handling in your viewmodel .

#### in xaml

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"  Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="LightPink">
        <Label Text="Select All" FontSize="Micro" TextColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" >
        </Label>
        <CheckBox x:Name="MultiselectCheckbox" ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"   IsChecked="{Binding MultiselectCheck}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Color="Red"></CheckBox>
    </StackLayout>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
     x:Name="Listview"          
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                  
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <ViewCell >

                        <Frame Padding="0" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Red" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                </Label>
                                <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Color="Red" HorizontalOptions="End" >
                                </CheckBox>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>

                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    bool isMultiselect;
    bool isSingleSelect;
    public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyItems { get; set; }

    private bool multiselectCheck;
    public bool MultiselectCheck
    {

        get
        {
            return multiselectCheck;
        }

        set
        {
            if (multiselectCheck != value)
            {
                multiselectCheck = value;

                if(!isSingleSelect)
                {
                    isMultiselect = true;

                    foreach (MyData data in MyItems)
                    {
                        data.Selected = value;
                    }

                    isMultiselect = false;
                }

                NotifyPropertyChanged("MultiselectCheck");
            }
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyData>() {

             new MyData(){name="Selection1" },
             new MyData(){name="Selection2" },
             new MyData(){name="Selection3" },

        };


        foreach(MyData data in MyItems)
        {
            data.PropertyChanged += Data_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }
```